# Handling multipart attachments in CXF APIs

Tags: cxf, inputstream, multipart

I am trying to develop an API call using Apache CXF that takes in an attachment along with the request. I followed [this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html) tutorial and this is what I have got so far.

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@RequireAuthentication(false)
public Response uploadWadl(MultipartBody multipartBody){
    List<Attachment> attachments = multipartBody.getAllAttachments();
    DataHandler dataHandler = attachments.get(0).getDataHandler();
    try {
        InputStream is = dataHandler.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response("OK");
}
```

I am getting an InputStream object to the attachment and everything is working fine. However I need to pass the attachment as a java.io.File object to another function. I know I can create a file here, read from the inputstream and write to it. But is there a better solution? Has the CXF already stored it as a File? If so I could just go ahead and use that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

I'm also interested on this matter. While discussing with Sergey on the CXF mailing list, I learned that CXF is using a temporary file if the attachment is over a certain threshold.

In the process I discovered this [blogpost](http://ext2xhb.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/using-cxf-attachment-safely/) that explains how to use CXF attachment safely.
You can be interested by the exemple on [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAX-RS+Multiparts#JAX-RSMultiparts-Writingattachments) as well.

That's all I can say at the moment as I'm investigating right now, I hope that helps.

---

EDIT : At the moment here's how we handle attachment with CXF 2.6.x. About uploading a file using multipart content type.

In our REST resource we have defined the following method :

```java
  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Path("/")
  public Response archive(
          @Multipart(value = "title", required = false) String title,
          @Multipart(value = "hash", required = false) @Hash(optional = true) String hash,
          @Multipart(value = "file") @NotNull Attachment attachment) {

    ...

    IncomingFile incomingFile = attachment.getObject(IncomingFile.class);

    ...
  }
```

A few notes on that snippet :

- `@Multipart` is not standard to JAXRS, it's not even in JAXRS 2, it's part of CXF.
- In our code we have implemented bean validation (you have to do it yourself in JAXRS 1)
- You don't have to use a `MultipartBody`, the key here is to use an argument of type `Attachment`

So yes as far as we know there is not yet a possibility to get directly the type we want in the method signature. So for example if you just want the `InputStream` of the attachment you cannot put it in the signature of the method. You have to use the `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment` type and write the following statement :

```java
InputStream inputStream = attachment.getObject(InputStream.class);
```

Also we discovered with the help of *Sergey Beryozkin* that we could transform or wrap this `InputStream`, that's why in the above snippet we wrote :

```java
IncomingFile incomingFile = attachment.getObject(IncomingFile.class);
```

`IncomingFile` is our custom wrapper around the `InputStream`, for that you have to register a `MessageBodyReader`, `ParamHandler` won't help as they don't work with streams but with `String`.

```java
@Component
@Provider
@Consumes
public class IncomingFileAttachmentProvider implements MessageBodyReader<IncomingFile> {
  @Override
  public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return type != null && type.isAssignableFrom(IncomingFile.class);
  }

  @Override
  public IncomingFile readFrom(Class<IncomingFile> type,
                              Type genericType,
                              Annotation[] annotations,
                              MediaType mediaType,
                              MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
                              InputStream entityStream
  ) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    return createIncomingFile(entityStream, fixedContentHeaders(httpHeaders)); // the code that will return an IncomingFile
  }
}
```

Note however that there have been a few trials to understand what was passed, how, and the way to hot-fix bugs *(For example the first letter of the first header of the attachment part was eat so you had `ontent-Type` instead of `Content-Type`)*.

Of course the `entityStream` represents the actual `InputStream` of the attachment. This stream will read data either from memory or from disk, depending on where CXF put the data ; there is a size threshold property (`attachment-memory-threshold`) for that matter. You can also say where the temporary attachments will go (`attachment-directory`).

Just don't forget to **close the stream** when you are done (some tool do it for you).

Once everything was configured we tested it with [Rest-Assured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) from *Johan Haleby*. *(Some code are part of our test utils though)* :

```java
given().log().all()
        .multiPart("title", "the.title")
        .multiPart("file", file.getName(), file.getBytes(), file.getMimeType())
.expect().log().all()
        .statusCode(200)
        .body("store_event_id", equalTo("1111111111"))
.when()
        .post(host().base().endWith("/store").toStringUrl());
```

Or if you need to upload the file via curl in such a way :

```
curl --trace -v -k -f
     --header "Authorization: Bearer b46704ff-fd1d-4225-9dd4-e29065532b73"
     --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
     --form "hash={SHA256}3e954efb149aeaa99e321ffe6fd581f84d5a497b6fab5c86e0d5ab20201f7eb5"
     --form "title=fantastic-video.mp4"
     --form "archive=@/the/path/to/the/file/fantastic-video.mp4;type=video/mp4"
     -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/video/event/store
```

To finish this answer, I'd like to mention it is possible to have JSON payload in multipart, for that you can use an `Attachment` type in the signature and then write

```java
Book book = attachment.getObject(Book.class)
```

Or you can write an argument like :

```java
@Multipart(value="book", type="application/json") Book book
```

Just don't forget to add the `Content-Type` header to the relevant part when performing the request.

It might be worth to say that it is possible to have all the parts in a list, just write a method with a single argument of type `List<Attachment>`. However I prefer to have the actual arguments in the method signature as it's cleaner and less boilerplate.

```java
@POST
void takeAllParts(List<Attachment> attachments)
```