# Camel-CXF REST: How to send to CXF web service more than one parameter on payload in REST client?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, apache-camel, cxf

I have a CXF web service with exactly one parameter that should be sent on the payload. All the other parameters are sent on the URL:

Parameter class:

```
class Book
{
    String name;
    String author;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Service:

```
@Post
@Path("/addBook/{roomId}/{bookId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@WebResult(name = "addBookResponse")
public LibraryResponse addBook(
        @PathParam("roomId") @WebParam(name = "roomId") String roomId,
        @PathParam("bookId") @WebParam(name = "bookId") String bookId,
        @WebParam(name = "book") Book book);
```

The payload I send in the REST client:

```
{
    "name":"War and Peace",
    "author":"Lev Tolstoy"
}
```

In this simple case it works. :)

Now, I have another CXF web service method with two parameters that should be sent on the payload:

```
@PUT
@Path("/replaceBook/{roomId}/{bookId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@WebResult(name = "replaceBookResponse")
public LibraryResponse replaceBook(
        @PathParam("roomId") @WebParam(name = "roomId") String roomId,
        @PathParam("bookId") @WebParam(name = "bookId") String bookId,
        @WebParam(name = "originalBook") Book originalBook,
        @WebParam(name = "newBook") Book newBook);
```

What should I send as the payload? I have tried to send the following payload but it did not work.

```
[
    {
        "name": "The Da Vinci Code",
        "author": "Dan Brown"
    },
    {
        "name": "War and Peace",
        "author": "Lev Tolstoy"
    }
]
```

**Probably the following is how to do it:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13253070/784980

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAX-RS+Multiparts

https://ext2xhb.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/using-cxf-attachment-safely/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "originalBook": {
    "name": "The Da Vinci Code",
    "author": "Dan Brown"
  },
  "newBook": {
    "name": "War and Peace",
    "author": "Lev Tolstoy"
  }
}
```

Comment: Already tried it and several other variants. Getting `org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "originalBook" (Class Book), not marked as ignorable`

Comment: Are you calling correct method? It sounds like your method is expecting a `Book` object and then attempts to find `Book`s property `originalBook`

Comment: @Germann Arlington I do not understand your comment. `replaceBook(...)` expects two Book objects (and several path parameters) so I am trying to send them. The exception simply means that the syntax of the JSON I send as payload does not match the expected syntax. It's interpreted as if I was trying to send one object with two fields, `originalBook` and `newBook`. Conclusion: the suggested syntax is wrong.

Comment: But the error message says `Unrecognized field "originalBook" (Class Book)` - to me it sounds like it is trying to map your parameter named `originalBook` to a field **in** class `Book` - but I may be mistaken

Comment: @Germann Arlington to answer your question, I am absolutely sure that I am calling the correct method.